# give an example of algebraic numbers $\alpha, \beta$ such that....

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Question is to find algebraic numbers $\alpha, \beta$ such that :

$$[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]>[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}]>[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\beta):\mathbb{Q}]$$

It is not so difficult to find algebraic numbers $\alpha, \beta$ such that :
$$[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]>[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}]$$

but then the last relation $$[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}]>[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\beta):\mathbb{Q}]$$is getting disturbed all the time....

Please provide some hint for me to clear this.

Thank you :)

Comment: This is not as easy as one might expect ...

Comment: $$\frac16+\frac13=\frac12$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : so helpful... as always :)

Comment: Just riffing on the hint in Ayman's temporarily deleted (+1) answer ;-) As a 10k+ member I knew that you had seen it (we have the privilege to see deleted answers).

Comment: Ok Ok :)$~~~~~~~~$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I actually had a slightly more complicated example, but the idea is the same. I deleted my hint because I felt it wasn't helpful. It's undeleted now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can argument this way. Suppose that we can find some $\alpha$ with the following properties:

1) $[\mathbb Q(\alpha)\colon \mathbb Q]=n$ and there is some prime $p$ such that $p(p+1)\mid n$.

2) The minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $\alpha$ is of the form $f(x^{p(p+1)})$ for some $f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$.

Then $[\mathbb Q(\alpha^p)\colon \mathbb Q]=n/p$. In fact clearly $[\mathbb Q(\alpha^p)\colon\mathbb Q]$ is at least $n/p$, but also $\alpha^p$ is a root of $f(x^{p+1})$ which has degree $n/p$, and so is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^p$. In the same way, one checks that $[\mathbb Q(\alpha^{p+1})\colon \mathbb Q]=n/(p+1)$ and since $\alpha^{p+1}=\alpha\cdot\alpha^p$ your example is found since $n>n/p>n/(p+1)$.

This allows you to construct a lot of examples. Pick your favourite $n$ divided by $p(p+1)$ for some prime $p$, then take any irreducible polynomial $m(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$ of degree $n$ of the form $f(x^{p(p+1)})$ for some $f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$. Then any root $\alpha$ of $m$ does the job. To construct $m(x)$ one can simply use Eisenstein's criterion.

To give an "explicit" example say that you choose $n=24=(3\cdot 4)\cdot 2$, so that $p=3$. Now fix your favourite prime number $q$ and set $m(x)=x^{24}+qx^{12}+q$. This polynomial is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion and is of the form $f(x^{12})$ where $f(x)=x^2+qx+q$. If $\alpha$ is a root of $m$, then $[\mathbb Q(\alpha)\colon \mathbb Q]=24$, $[\mathbb Q(\alpha^3)\colon \mathbb Q]=8$ because $x^8+qx^4+q$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^3$ and $[\mathbb Q(\alpha^4)\colon \mathbb Q]=6$ because the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^4$ is $x^6+qx^3+q$. Therefore $\alpha$ and $\beta=\alpha^3$ do the job.

Comment: I like this so much particularly " The minimal polynomial $p(x)$ of $α$ is of the form $f(x^{p(p+1)})$ for some $f(x)∈Z[x]$." I could not understand your idea...if $p(p+1)\mid n$ I could not see why is it obvious that $f(x^{p(p+1)})$ is its minimal polynomial... I am working on that... do you want to say something more about this... That would be so helpful for me...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I don't claim anything on the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, I am asking for it to be of that particular shape. I expanded my answer, I hope that the idea is clear now.

Comment: This makes lot of sense to me now... i would work on this to understand it better... Thank you so much for your help... :)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Try products of $n^\text{th}$ roots of $2$ for different values of $n$.

---

Since a solution was posted already, here is what I had in mind:

Put $\alpha = 2^{1/4} 2^{1/3} 2^{1/2}$. $\beta = 2^{2/3} 2^{1/2}$. Then $\alpha \beta = 4 \cdot 2^{1/4}$.

Comment: yes yes i had similar idea but could not make something out of that... could you help me a bit more...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Do you want the answer? I can't think of a way to give another hint without giving away the answer.

Comment: no No do not reveal the answer... :O I would try for some more time :(

Comment: could you please share your intention behind guessing this numbers....

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik The idea is to make roots cancel out when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are multiplied. I tried the smallest numbers I could think of, and I got an example.

Comment: I do not understand if that is so obvious for you why would it take so much time for me to realize :O Thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 3):

How about $\alpha=\sqrt[6]{2}$, $\beta=\sqrt[3]{2}$. Then $\alpha\beta=\sqrt{2}$, i.e.

$$[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=6>[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}]=3>[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\beta):\mathbb{Q}]=2$$

Comment: I would have posted a similar answer myself, but  Praphulla asked for hints, not full solutions.

Comment: @toooldformath : you could have given some hint.... Thanks for your interest anyways....

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Sorry for that. Next time ;).